# How do I add a border to a cell group in an InsetGroupedListStyle List in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

Given the following View

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  
  init() {
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      Text("foo").listRowBackground(Color.gray)
      Text("bar").listRowBackground(Color.gray)
      Text("foo").listRowBackground(Color.gray)
      Text("bar").listRowBackground(Color.gray)
    }
    .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
  }
}
```

which renders as follows

[image]

How would one add a border around the list elements following the rounded corner of the InsetGroupedListStyle like this red border

[image]

I have tried adding borders and shadows to either the List or the cells but they never match an insetGrouped cell "block".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add border will not work in this way because Apple have standards for List layouts and we can't modify those. To achieve your requirement we have to do our own customization by dividing them into sections and keeping VStack in each section.

[image]please check my below code which provides border to each `section`.

```
var body: some View {
      List {
          Section {
              VStack {
                  ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                      HStack {
                          Text(item)
                          Spacer()
                      }
                      .padding(8)
                      
                      if items.last != item {
                          Divider()
                      }
                  }
              }
              .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .circular).stroke(Color(uiColor: .tertiaryLabel), lineWidth: 1)
                              )
          }
      }
      .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
      
  }
```

Comment: what about list with section header?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the separate divider and not the one that apple uses by default, you add the .overlay modifier in the List and you can use frame or padding to adjust it to the size you want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbY4Z.png)

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var example = ["Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1",]

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section {
            VStack {
                ForEach(example, id: \.self) { item in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(item)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(8)
                        Divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .circular).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
    )
    .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .padding(.vertical, 180)
}
```

}